# Show that the eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Do you think my proof is correct ?

$$Ax_1=e_1x_1\\
Ax_2 = e_2x_2\\
$$
$$A(x_1+x_2)=e_1x_1+e_2x_2$$

Since $A(x_1+x_2)$ is

Comment: $A(x_1+x_2)$ is what

Comment: Supposing $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the eigenvalues, your approach can be employed to some extend. However, note that if either $e_1$ or $e_2$ is equal to zero, then this does not work and the statement does not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Av=av$, $Aw=bw$ and $v\not=w$, $v,w \not= 0$, and wlog $b \not=0$.

Then suppose by absurd that $w=kv$ for some $k \in \mathbb R$.

So $bw=Aw=Akv=kAv=kav \implies k=ka/b \implies a=b$.